# 1 duplicate symbol for architecture i386

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am facing a critical problem here, Xcode throws strange exception while building it's 
"

> duplicate symbol _selected in:
>       /Users/mhgaber/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/اProject-Name-aopcbghvorqhdwbyudzqsyhtekcu/Build/Intermediates/Project-Name.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Project-Name.build/Objects-normal/i386/ClassX.o
>       /Users/mhgaber/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Project-Name-aopcbghvorqhdwbyudzqsyhtekcu/Build/Intermediates/Project-Name.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Project-Name.build/Objects-normal/i386/ClassY.o
>   ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture i386
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I searched a lot but I didn't find anything help me please

Comment: Where did you declare _selected?

Comment: Did you accidently declare a .m file rather than a .h?

Comment: have you tried to do #import "headerfile.h" when there is not an actual headerfile.h?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Look at both the files for `ClassX` and `ClassY` - What targets are they included in? Basically the `_selected` method is duplicated in both of them. I am going to guess this is a plain C method that happens to be named the same in both files. Try renaming `_selected` in one of the files.

Comment: Really appreciate your help it was an integer variable that make all these problems

Comment: I had duplicate global integer variable in @implementation section of 2 classes. Thx.

Comment: Great explanation ! I was trying to fix  "missing required architecture i386 in file" error, all along... And the solution was that i forgot same name method in 2 classes... oh, xcode..

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I was declaring a `const` in a header file, which worked fine when building and running on the device (iPhone 5), however when attempting to simulate a 4S, all of a sudden I had some 300 "duplicate symbols".

It turns out I needed to also mark the `const` as `static` and the issue went away. Presumably it was trying to redefine the constant every time the header was referenced. The compiler isn't smart enough to just make constants static? Didn't think that would be necessary, but I guess it is.

```
const CGFloat kTitleAnimateDistance = 50.f;
```

Needed to be:

```
const static CGFloat kTitleAnimateDistance = 50.f;
```

Answer (score 3):

Some time you accidentally importing the .m file instead of the .h due to which this error comes. Please check and If this is not the reason, then perform the following steps

1- Check Build phases in Target settings.

2- Go to compile source section.

3- Check if any file exists twice or once.

4- If file exist twice delete one.

5- Build again.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and @dtrotzjr 's answer gave me a hint as to what could be causing it.

In my case I had a plain C `void` function in my framework (which xcode was complaining about as a duplicate symbol) and i needed to declare it as  `static void`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I was including a .h file with a number of const strings, methods and a struct. When I changed them all to static except the only mutable variable I wanted, it compiled just fine.